# How to disable hotkeys in bootstrap-wysiwyg? ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, hotkeys

I have bootstrap-wysiwyg attached into my ASP MVC project, but i have problem with hotkeys. I don't want them, i use this shortcuts for something else (like special characters).

How to disable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg), you can specify a hotkey map. Try supplying an empty map:

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg({
  hotKeys: {}
});
```

Or just omit the jQuery hotkeys script: `<script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>` which it requires.

Comment: First one. Easier than I thought ;)